# User Input to Output for JS function

Tags: javascript, html, converters

I'm trying to take user input from within an HTML file, convert it, and output it back to the page using `<input>` rather than prompt.

Here's what I have so far.

```
function bhedTester() {
    alpha = "ABC";
    bhed = "JYI";

    btext = "";
    i = 0;

    while (i < norm.length) {
        ind = alphabet.indexOf(norm.charAt(i));
        btext = btext + bhed.charAt(ind);
        i++;
    }
    btext
}
```

I've tested this using the prompt command and it works, but when I go to use

```
document.getElementById
```

OR

```
document.form_name._input_name.value
```

and then return that neither seems to work.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What is the error when it does not work? How are you exactly referencing the element?

Comment: Here's the fiddle that I've been trying to get it to work in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8628hr2s/1/)

Comment: ANd that showed your issue, you are not calling it when the input value is altered, you just call it when the page loads. Next you have a typo in it, `B` in getElementById.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further by what you mean? (The former, that is).

Comment: Please include all necessary code as a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a div you will have to do:

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML= bhedTester();
```

And after that you will need to return a string from the function you wrote.

Right now it is not returning anything.

So your code should look like:

```
    function bhedTester() {
    alpha = "ABC";
    bhed = "JYI";

    btext = "";
    i = 0;

    while (i < norm.length) {
        ind = alphabet.indexOf(norm.charAt(i));
        btext = btext + bhed.charAt(ind);
        i++;
    }
    return btext;
}
```

Since I don't know your `norm` and `alphabet` can't give you an exact solution.

Comment: It's basically like a substitution cipher. The letters are just in a different order. I only left three as a test point.

Comment: Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8628hr2s/1/) I've been trying it out in. Can't seem to get that return back to the page to appear.

Comment: @ZynVak Where are you getting the alphabet from?

Comment: [Here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Al_Bhed). Just something to test my knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

If you're triggering this function from a DOM event you have to return btext.

```
function bhedTester() {
  var alpha = "ABC";
  var bhed = "JYI";

  var btext = "";
  var i = 0;

  while (i < norm.length) {
    var ind = alphabet.indexOf(norm.charAt(i));
    btext = btext + bhed.charAt(ind);
    i++;
  }
  return btext
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for when either the text is changed in the input or when the button is clicked. Your code just runs when the page loads. It does not magically run when you type text. You need to alter it to run when the user changes the text. So you need to use addEventListener to bind the event.

```js
//bind the change event
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var textbox = this, //reference the textbox
        value = this.value;  //get what the user typed
    document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = value;  //set the value
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" />
<div id="bar" />
```

Now if you want to run it when the user is typing, than use the keyup event.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't sure if this is what i was missing or not. Makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: So I have added this in as you mentioned and when I run it, it appears to take in the value I input but nothing is sent back out.

Comment: So did you fix the typo I mentioned with getElementById in your original code?

Comment: Yup. I think the issue is with my `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = bhedTester();`